# Mongo: query by key one level deep

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to use something like 'exists'  in a Mongo query to return this record based on an ID?

Something like *select where 'ids' contains key '123456'*?

```
  {
      "department": "Digging",
      "ids": {
        "123456": {
          "color": "blue"
        },
        "123457": {
          "color": "red"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you're searching for the existence of a field with a given name, $exists is the operator you need (see [Advanced Queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries)).

e.g. something like:

```
db.YourCollection.find({ "ids.123456" : {$exists: true}});
```

Comment: Perfect! What I really needed was the dot notation  `db.YourCollection.find({"ids.123456": {$exists: true}});`

Comment: is there more speedy way to do this or $exists only solution?