# Mongo query on keys in a object

Tags: mongodb

My document structure:

```
    { _id:objectID,
     month:'2014-01'
     daily:{
            '01':{},
             '02':{},
             '03':{}
             .
             .
             .
             '31':{}


           }
  }
```

Now, i want to query objects in daily, which is in a range 08 to 13 (for say), means only objects greater 08 and less  than 13. These keys(01, 02,....31) in daily object are generated dynamically. I don't want to retrieve whole daily object and then process in backend. Please help.

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: This is a bad database design. You shouldn't have dates as keys - they should be values.

Comment: keys can be anything. And Mongodb has schemaless design. this should be fine.

Comment: var query = {month:'2014-01'};   var projection={daily:1}; Cliend.db.collection('monthlydata').find(query, projection).toArray().....then i iterate over daily object to find appropriate keys.

Comment: sashkello can you elaborate why its a bad design.

Comment: @Danish "then i iterate over daily object to find appropriate keys" - and you are still asking why this is bad design?

Comment: @Danish "keys can be anything" doesn't mean you *should* do anything and just go with it. Schemaless design doesn't mean you shouldn't bother with designing your database. Keys are basically names of your fields. All the MDB queries, map reduce, etc are designed to work on values and keys are just ways to refer to those objects.

Comment: @Danish When you are designing database your first thought should be: "How will I do these most useful queries?" You should design your database based on what queries you are going to run on it. If you run into trouble running the simplest of queries, this means the design is not good. In this case it is fundamentally wrong...

Comment: @sashkello you're right. we are developing a Big Data product, we have given much thought on schema design and this very much serves our purpose coz most of the time we query to retrieve all of 'daily' and similar objects but sometimes query to retrieve part of daily or to know whether a particular day exists in daily or not. this can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776151/mongo-query-by-key-one-level-deep?rq=1

Comment: @sashkello thanks for the discussion :)

Comment: @Danish Why not to split these into separate documents? You can then index on month and day and have a nice quick and simple query. You can have three fields: year, month, day, all numeric without string search or any other unnecessary stuff. Nested designs like these can turn ugly when it is too late...

Answer (score 1):

You can't query for slices out of an embedded array. Since the `daily` array is embedded in the month document, you can't treat its individual entries as individual objects.

If your query looks for individual days, you should consider modeling your data appropriately, by creating a single document for each day. e.g.:

```
{
  _id: { month: '2014-01', day: 1 },
  /* rest of daily data here */
}
```

This will allow you to query for particular days with or without a specific month.